# How to automatically sign users up for Alerts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar

I would like Alerts to be created for updates to a changed List item.  I would like them to fire off to both the Creator of the event, as well as the users listed in a multi-valued people picker field.  I want these to be the OOB Alerts (not custom alerts) to leverage the formatting of the OOB alerts.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add alerts to the alertcollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spalertcollection_members.aspx) in an evenhandler. However this might introduce some problems as the user needs to be able to add others to alerts unless you elevate the priveleges.

something like this. It's only a head pseudo but I hope it gives inspiration

```
RunElevated
{
    foreach user in alertgroup
    {
        spalert newalert = user.alerts.add()
        newalert.alerttype = spalerttype.item
        newalert.item = currentitem
        newalert.properties["eventtypeindex"] = "0"
        newalert.alertfrequency = spalertfrequency.immediate
        newalert.update(false)
    }   
}
```

Comment: do you think you could provide some more concrete steps? sorry I'm not a dev, but if I have more detail I can write a quick spec up for my dev.  So the object is that the people in that field are provided the nice oob alert (not a custom one we write) -

Comment: hope the example helps.